# Adding rows the manual way in 2-D arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

User inputs desired amount of `rows` and `columns`, then if any row is found with even numbers the code should add a duplicate row below it. But instead I get no anwswer. Help needed. I only need to add rows with this manual method. I know their are much stable ways with vectors. But right now this is only way for me.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int rows, columns;
std::cout << "Enter the number of rows: ";
std::cin >> rows;
std::cout << "Enter the number of columns: ";
std::cin >> columns;


//-----------------------Generating 2-D array---------------------------------------------------------
int **array = new int*[2 * rows]; // allocating memory for the array
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    array[i] = new int[columns];
//-----------------------Input Array Elements---------------------------------------------------------
std::cout << "Enter the elements" << std::endl;
for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
        std::cin >> array[i][j];
//--------------------Loop for the array output--------------------------------------------------------
for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
        std::cout << array[i][j] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
//-------------------Loop for finding rows with even numbers And adding the clone rows----------------------------------------
for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
        if (array[i][j] % 2 == 0) {
            for (int k = rows; k > i; k--) {
                for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
                    array[k][j] = array[k - 1][j];
                    ;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
            array[i + 1][j] = 0;
        i++;
        columns++;
    }
}

std::cout << "\n";
//--------------------Loop for the answer OUTPUT--------------------------
for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
        std::cout << array[i][j] << " ";
}
std::cout << "\n";
}

return 0;
}
```

For example if we enter an array
1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 5
The answer should be
1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2 -------> even
2 2 2 2 2 --------> Duplicate
3 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4 ---------> Even
4 4 4 4 4 ----------> clone
5 5 5 5 5

Comment: There's too much wrong with this code to really know how to help. Firstly, where do you think you are *adding* a row? If you add a row then somewhere you have to allocate some more memory for it, but you don't do that. Secondly your logic is wrong as you try to add a row for each even number. For every even number you find you try to add a row, but from your description you should duplicate each row that contains any even numbers. So first search for an even number anywhere in the row, and only when you checked all the numbers in a row duplicate it if you found at least one even number.

Comment: Probably the best advice is to break the problem down. For instance don't worry about even numbers and duplication, just write some code that adds a row to a 2d array (including allocating more memory for the extra row). That's an easier problem and until you've solved that you aren't going to be able to solve the bigger problem. Once you've solved that problem you can but the code in a seperate function and use that function to solve the bigger problem. At the moment I think you are trying to run before you can walk.

Comment: you are use J variable 2 times in two different for when one loop are inside the other loop. This is wrong.

Comment: @john , You can see from the comments , where I am trying to add the `duplicate` `rows` after the `rows` with even numbers

Comment: @Prog Yes you are trying but you aren't doing it right, as I explained in my comments.